# Profile Form for site is not updating certain fields

Tags: profile

Site: dcssinc.com
Form: dcssinc.com/contact-us/
WordPress: 4.5.2
CiviCRM: 4.4

Fields that do not update information:

-Position
-Project State
-Comment

Only the position field is a custom field.

I have reviewed the settings for each field and I do not see anything that would make these fields behave differently than the rest.

Please advise :-)

Comment: Hi LGB. is this a public page? want to share the url? what is 'comment' since that doesn't sound like a core field

Comment: Which minor release of 4.4 are you using? Is there any possibility of upgrading to the latest long term support release (the 4.6.x branch?) You might find this solves the issue, but might be a bit of work to upgrade.

Comment: Hi  petednz - fuzion, http://dcssinc.com/contact-us/

Comment: Hi  petednz - fuzion, the page is http://dcssinc.com/contact-us/ and the comments field is a Contacts - Note(s) labelled Comment.

Hi John, you're right updating is an option but it is a lot of work, I would like to see if this can be fixed and if not then I will look into pursuing updating.

Comment: I have updated to CiviCRM 4.6.16 LTS and the problem still exists. Custom fields that are added to the profile form does not update properly in the email that is sent to an administrator, but it does update the information for the contact correctly in the back-end when viewing the contact.

Updated Specs: WordPress 4.5.2 CiviCRM 4.6.16 LTS